# symfony2 slot out append "1" to end of string

Tags: symfony

in the view file am setting value like the follwoing

```
<?php $view['slots']->set('title', 'Job Alert Subscribers') ?>
```

in layout

```
<?php echo $view['slots']->output('title','');?>
```

But in the output am getting like the follwoing

Job Alert Subscribers1

"1" value get's added to end of the string, why is this happening ?

Comment: Could you paste all "layout"? Thanks

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Dashboard">
    <meta name="keyword" content="Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
    <title>Admin / <?php echo $view['slots']->output('title','');?></title>

Comment: i got it we dont have to use echo in <?php echo $view['slots']->output('title','');?>   just use  <?php  $view['slots']->output('title','');?>  , thank you @user1679267 for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
<?php echo $view['slots']->output('title','');?>
```

You execute `output` method that already outputs to the output buffer your title variable. But then you try to echo the result of this method. As it successfully executed method will return `true`. And your line will be interpreted like:

```
<?php echo true; ?>
```

And exactly this `true` will be converted to `1` in the echo statement.